# A number is drawn from 1 to 500. What is the probabilty that the number is not divisable by 2, 3 and 5?

Tags: probability

A number is drawn from 1 to 500. What is the probabilty that the number is not divisable by 2, 3 and 5? I was thinking about doing the complement of each occurance , then a intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number is divisible by $2$, $3$ and $5$ if and only if it's divisible by $30$. Now, how many numbers divisible by $30$ lie between $1$ and $500$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a discrete random drawing and you mean that the number must not be divisible by any of 2, 3, or 5, you can simply count the number of multiples of 30. That is, the probability is $1 -\frac{16}{500} = 0.968$.